# I get "IndexError: list index out of range" error on server, but not on local machine

Tags: python

I made a python script that crawls the web page at 'http://spys.one/en/socks-proxy-list/' and fetches all the IP addresses there, then checks if they're up and finally returns a list of all live Ip addresses. then there's a second script which connects to telegrams bot API and uses the first script to show the user a list of recent socks5 working servers.

I'm an amateur programmer and new to Python programming language. I made these scripts for exercise. feel free to point out my mistakes and show the ways I can improve my code. thanks in advance!

```
import requests as req
import re
import socket


def is_open(ip, port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        s.connect((ip, int(port)))
        s.shutdown(2)
        return True
    except:
        return False


# Initial settings:
url = 'http://spys.one/en/socks-proxy-list/'
regex = '\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}'

# Request URL
response = req.get(url).text

# Extract IP and port from source
p = re.compile(regex)
results = p.findall(response)

# Fetch and check the first 20 IPs
alive = []
for i in range(0, 20):
    if is_open(results[i], '1080'):
        alive.append(results[i])


def gimmeprox():
    links = []
    for x in range(0,len(alive)):
        links.append('https://t.me/proxy?server=' + alive[int(x)] + '&port=1080')

    payload = '\n\n'.join(links)
    return payload
```

When I run this code and the other (bot) script, everything works fine, but as soon as I put it on the web (heroku, etc.) it crashes on line 30:

```
line 30, in <module>
    if is_open(results[i], '1080'):
```

with the error `""`.

Comment: with what error?

Comment: If there are fewer than 20 results you will get this error.

Comment: What is the value of `response`? What is the value of `results`?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: "results" does not always have 20 items. So, you're basically asking for something that doesn't exist.

You should always check the length before iterating over; or in these scenarios when you don't need the index, simply iterate over the actual items rather than the index.

Comment: I checked for that by adding a "print" statement printing the iterator and list member inside the for loop; all was fine!

Answer (score 1):

When you run

```
for i in range(20):
    if is_open(results[i], '1080'):
        alive.append(results[i])
```

and `len(results)` is <20, you will eventually try to access `results[len(results)]`, resulting in an IndexError. To prevent this, choose the lower value of `len(results)` and 20 as your argument for `range`, like so: ***`min(len(results), 20)`***.

An alternative is to loop through all values of `results` and break when you have 20.

```
for r in result:
    if is_open(r, '1080'):
        alive.append(r)
    if len(alive) >= 20:  # shouldn't actually get over 20, just a precaution
        break
```